# save this png to phone gallery in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

```
 void _show(PictureDetails picture, BuildContext context) {
setState(() {
  _finished = true;
});

Navigator.of(context)
    .push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: const Text('your image'),
    ),
    body: new Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: new FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
          future: picture.toPNG(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Uint8List> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                } else {


                  return Image.memory(snapshot.data!);
                }
            
              default:
                return new Container(
                    child: new FractionallySizedBox(
                      widthFactor: 0.1,
                      child: new AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 1.0,
                          child: new CircularProgressIndicator()),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                    ));
            }
          },
        )),
  );
}));
```

}
}

this class displays the png image on the screen, but next step is to save it to the phone gallery.
i tried many dependencies to save the image to gallery, but unfortunately none of them worked for me.
i want a button anywhere on the screen and on pressing which the image gets saved in gallery.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/folder_file_saver can use this package for saving your file to device

Comment: it saves images only through url. im my case i have the image in png format already

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_utilities check this

Comment: not working either

Comment: strange as it worked for me !!